# assembly-c from windows 10 command prompt

Tags: c, assembly, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm trying learning assembly language and i need to know how to read the assembly varsion of a c program from the windows 10 command prompt.
I've tried using `C:\users\prete\Desktop\booksrc$ gcc -g firstprog.c` but it doesn't work

please help me
thank you!

Comment: Do you mean something like adding the option `-S` to the command line and using a text editor to look at firstprog.s?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a good problem description. What happens? What's the exact error you get? Do you even have `gcc` installed? Can you run it? Do you just have problem with getting the assembly listing?

Comment: @PeterCordes : Jester may be onto something I didn't catch at first. The OPis getting an error which could suggest this is a GCC installation issue or GCC not being on the path.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I wondered that, too, but no point in anyone wasting their time answering the current question until / unless the OP edits the question to clarify, e.g. with an actual error message to make a [mcve].  As asked, it's either a non-MCVE or a duplicate, so for now at least it should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about windows, but as far as I know, the assembly output is gained by the `-S` option for gcc.

Try `gcc -S firstprog.c`

The output will be `firstprog.s` in AT&T syntax. If you want it in the intel syntax (might be rather helpful if you use NASM/MASM/YASM and such for assembling), try:

```
gcc -S -masm=intel firstprog.c
```